# Убирать и убор

Tags: однокоренные-слова

"Убирать" - значит удалять что-то, уносить. Но при этом "убор" - это украшение, одежда (головной убор). Почему такие разные по значению слова (я бы даже сказала, противоположные) являются однокоренными?
Спасибо

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Убирать - это не только удалять, уносить, но так же - наводить порядок, чистоту. Головной убор позволяет привести волосы в порядок, убрать их из виду, как и одеяние - убранство скрывает недостатки, т.е. убирает их из виду. Так что, по сути, не так уж и далеки эти слова между собой.